# in sonarqube- SELECT command denied to user 'sonar_user'@'localhost' for table 'session_variables

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube-4.5

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (SELECT command denied to user
>   'sonar_user'@'localhost' for table 'session_variables')
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
>   ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
>   ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
>           at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>   ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
>           at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:113)
>   ~[sonar-core-4.5.5.jar:na]
>           ... 27 common frames omitted Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT
>   command denied to user 'sonar_user'@'localhost' for table
>   'session_variables'
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SonarQube server connects to the database with a user (`'sonar_user'@'localhost'`) who does not have sufficient privileges (as per error message, it cannot issue `SELECT` commands in the database).

You need to grant this permission to this user in the MySQL DB (here's a [helpful tutorial](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/grant-permissions-to-a-mysql-user-on-linux-via-command-line/) on how to achieve that).

Comment: :) If it solved your problem than you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer

Answer (score 0):

### For accessing GLOBAL|SESSION VARIABLES try with command in MYSQL:

$ GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

$ GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

### If it is not working then you should try(It only provide SELECT permission to 'sonar' user for all DATABASES):

$ GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

$ GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

### It provides permission to sonar user to access all the databases with all the privilege SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE (ALL possible moves on DB).

$ GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

$ GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';